# What does "node module wrapper function" mean in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to know what "module wrapper function" means and what it does to my code.

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {  
       
    
 });
```

Comment: Where do you find this wrapper that includes `process` and `global`?  The wrapper in the [node.js doc](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper), does not include those.  The other arguments are module-specific variables so this is how node.js makes them uniquely defined for each module by inserting your module code inside this function before the code is processed and then it calls your code via this function and passes it these module-specific arguments.

Comment: Relevant node.js source code that shows the wrapper: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L124

Answer (score 14):

### Original Answer

According to the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper),

> Before a module's code is executed, Node.js will wrap it with a function
>   wrapper that looks like the following:
>
> ```
> (function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 
>     // Module code actually lives in here 
> });
> ```
>
> By doing this, Node.js achieves a few
>   things:
>
> - It keeps top-level variables (defined with var, const or let) scoped
>     to the module rather than the global object.
> - It helps to provide some
>     global-looking variables that are actually specific to the module,
>     such as:
>
>   - The module and exports objects that the implementor can use
>       to export values from the module.
>   - The convenience variables __filename
>       and __dirname, containing the module's absolute filename and directory
>       path.

Essentially, this wrapper is used to configure your module, and it **enables the use of the variables `exports`, `require`, `module`, `__filename`, and `__dirname`.**

### Edit

OP also mentions the `process` and `global` variables.

- **The `process` object gives information about, and control over, the current Node.js process.**

  - It emits events such as `exit` and `uncaughtException` to manage the Node process.
  - It also includes functions such as `process.abort()` to end the current process.
  - To see all of the information, see the [Node documentation on `process`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html)
- **`global` provides a system for accessing and setting global variables.**

  - For example, if you do `global.something = true` in one module, in another module you can access `something` and it will be `true` (without having to export it).
  - Read more at the [Node `global` documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global).

### Edit 2

You can edit the wrapper, too:

```
let Module = require('module');

Module.wrap = (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
    // What you want the new wrapper to be.
    return Module.wrapper[0] + exports + 'console.log("This is the wrapper.");' + Module.wrapper[1];
});
```

Comment: The OP shows `global` and `process` in the wrapper too.  Can you explain where that comes from?

Comment: @jfriend00 OK, I've added a section about that.

Comment: sorry.. it was a mistake.in node js originally it not included. However, I would like to ask that changes of this module wrapper function are possible...

Comment: Nobody is asking what `process` and `global` are.  The OP shows them in the wrapper.  The node.js source code and doc do not show them in the wrapper.  That's what I was asking about.  That's the part of what the OP shows that you do not address.

Comment: @yasiru Yes, you can change the wrapper. I've added a section about that. Basically, you can change `require('module').wrapper` to whatever you like.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you can just do `let Module = require('module');`?  In the node.js source code, that looks like an internal module that you can't directly get to.

Comment: @jfriend00 It seems editable to me. Granted, you have to follow a pretty strict format in order for the code to properly function. I made a simple [demo in repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/BigSlightChief) demonstrating a slight change that could be made.

Comment: @Marco Your demo is unavailable.

Answer (score 2):

I think, I'm little late on this post but I'd like to share my 2 cents here.

So the expression you have written is [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

Basically, your code in a (Node)file is wrapped inside this particular function. When someone requires this file, IIFE runs automatically and provides you objects such as module.exports, exports, __dirname, __filename.

These objects are not global but local to your module (file). And these are made available by this IIFE function. Using this object can export your module.

Link to the documentation is already provided in above answer, that should help.

Answer (score 1):

If you write some code, e.g.:

```
const fs = require("fs");
module.exports = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "test.txt");
process.exit();
```

Then you work with a lot of global variables that are not defined through the js spec, they are only available in node. To make them available to the code, the code you executed gets enclosed in the function you quoted which allows you to access them. They could also have written some C++ code to solve that but that would have been far more complicated.